# django 'ModelFormOptions' object has no attribute 'virtual_fields'

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Products(models.Model):
company = models.ForeignKey(Companys)
name = models.CharField(unique = True, max_length = 50)
description = models.CharField(unique = True, max_length = 500)
price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
in_stock = models.BooleanField(default = True)
crated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Products
    fields = '__all__'
name = forms.CharField()
description = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea, )
company = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Companys.objects.all(), label = 'Company')
in_stock = forms.BooleanField(initial = True)
price = forms.IntegerField()
```

views.py

```
class ProductCreate(CreateView, ProductEditMixin):
model = ProductForm
template_name = 'store/product_add.html'
fields = '__all__'
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.success_url = reverse('get_context_data', kwargs = {'pk' : Companys.objects.first().id})
    return super(ProductCreate, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Please help me. Without forms code work. But with forms i have AttributeError: 'ModelFormOptions' object has no attribute 'virtual_fields' error

Comment: can you show your view post method ? the method that you use to handle the post request

Comment: I add it but I have this error after commenting post and get_context_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProductForm is a form, not a model. It should go in the view's `form_class` attribute, not `model`.

(I also don't understand why your ProductForm uses the Company model rather than Product, but never mind.)

Comment: Before write question I was make some changes and forgot change Company to Products. Now code is work thank you